# How can I upgrade pip inside a venv inside a Dockerfile?

Tags: python, pip, dockerfile, python-venv

While running

> $ sudo docker build -t myproj:tag .

I am hit with the message

```
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

and given recent occasional subtleties manifesting themselves with the error:

```
"/usr/bin/pip" "from pip import main" "ImportError: cannot import .."
```

I'd rather yield and indeed upgrade.

And so I add the `pip upgrade` command in the `DockerFile`, *after* the venv is built, since the `pip` that matters is the one inside the venv (am I getting this right?). So my Dockerfile now has this:

```
...
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
...
```

But doing so does not avoid the "You are using pip 10.x" message. What am I missing?

**Update**

Though a promising suggestion, neither

```
RUN source venv/bin/activate
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

nor

```
RUN source venv/bin/activate
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

eliminate the "You are using pip version 10.0.1, ..." message.

Comment: can you share more of your Dockerfile? Like more `RUN` or `CMD` lines?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The single easiest answer to this is to just not bother with a virtual environment in a Docker image.  A virtual environment gives you an isolated filesystem space with a private set of Python packages that don't conflict with the system install, but so does a Docker image.  You can just use the system pip in a Docker image and it will be fine.

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install .
CMD ["myscript"]
```

If you really want a virtual environment, you either need to specifically run the wrapper scripts from the virtual environment's path

```
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

or run the virtual environment "activate" script on *every* RUN command; the environment variables it sets won't carry over from one step to another.  (Each RUN command in effect does its own `docker run; docker commit` sequence under the hood and will launch a new shell in a new container; the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) describes this a little bit.)

```
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN . venv/bin/activate \
 && pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . .
RUN . venv/bin/activate \
 && pip install .
CMD ["venv/bin/myscript"]
```

Trying to activate the virtual environment in its own RUN instruction does nothing beyond generate a no-op layer.

```
# This step does nothing
RUN . venv/bin/activate
# And therefore this upgrades the system pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Very nice and very convincing. Still (aside from the fact that you sound authoritative) could you provide a reference, or some reasoning, for the general principle that each command in a Dockerfile spawns its own shell, and that, in particular, entering a virtual environment will be transient? If all this meshes together, the biggest lesson is that one cannot dry-run a set of commands on an actual command line and then copy them to the Dockerfile.

Comment: I added a short section describing what [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) really does.  I can't find the exact wording I'm looking for in the Docker documentation (it keeps using "layer") but there's at least a mention that `RUN command` does so in a separate shell.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can use your virtual environment `venv`you need to activate it with

On Windows:

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

On Unix or MacOS, run:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Please note that venv is the name of your environment. You created this environment with `RUN python -m venv venv`. I strongly recommend to use a other name.

Then you can upgrade with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

After you create a virtual environment in a Docker container through

```
RUN python -m venv venv
```

then run either

```
RUN venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
RUN venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

but neither

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

nor

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```